# How to count the occurrences of a string and only print it out once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want my code to output each letter in the string only once and in alphabetical order, for example `banana` will output `abn`.

The catch is that I still need it to count the occurrences of each letter in the string, so the output should be as follows:

```
a occurs in the word banana a total of 3 times(s)
b occurs in the word banana a total of 1 time(s)
n occurs in the word banana a total of 2 time(s)
...
```

This is my code:

```
def letter_counter(string):
    stg = string.lower()
    stg = ''.join(sorted(stg))
    for i in stg:
        a = stg.count(i)
        print(f'the letter {i} appears in the word {string} {a} times')
            
letter_counter('banana')
```

And the current output is as follows:

```
the letter a appears in the word banana 3 times
the letter a appears in the word banana 3 times
the letter a appears in the word banana 3 times
the letter b appears in the word banana 1 times
the letter n appears in the word banana 2 times
the letter n appears in the word banana 2 times
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to easily count the letters for you:

```
from collections import Counter

def letter_counter(string):
    for letter, count in sorted(Counter(string.lower()).items()):
        print(f'the letter {letter} appears in the word {string} {count} times')

letter_counter("banana")
```

Gives:

```
the letter a appears in the word banana 3 times
the letter b appears in the word banana 1 times
the letter n appears in the word banana 2 times
```

Answer (score 0):

For unique letters you can try to use set().
So something like `for i in sorted(set(stg)):`

Answer (score 0):

The trick to remove duplicates is to make it a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
def letter_counter(string):
    stg = string.lower()
    stg = ''.join(stg)
    for i in sorted(set(stg)):
        a = stg.count(i)
        print(f'the letter {i} appears in the word {string} {a} time{"" if a == 1 else "s"}')

letter_counter('banana')
```

prints out:

```
the letter a appears in the word banana 3 times
the letter b appears in the word banana 1 time
the letter n appears in the word banana 2 times
```

Note the move from `sorted` one line later. A `set` is *unordered* so the original sorted order is lost. Sorting it again, just before looping, sorts this out.

Comment: This fixed all my issues also I took out one line of code because we don't need to have the stg = ''.join(stg) line as the line you presented does that anyway! Thankyou!